# Accessing Dependency of one layer in another layer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Can we have access to a dependency in DAO layer in any other layers like Controller,Service in a java project

Comment: yes you can. but let us know what problem you are facing

Comment: Technically, yes! However, it depends what you are trying to do.

Comment: I was asking from the conceptual point of view. If the answer is yes , then how we can access it ?